# How to write a query to ensure email contains @

Tags: sql, db2, check-constraints

I'm creating a database in db2 and I want to add a constrain to validate whether the user inserting a valid email address, that contain %@%.% . Without luck...any advice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use LIKE with wildcards. See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/c0011568.htm) for the wildcards on DB2.

> The underscore character ( _ ) represents any single character.
>
> The percent sign character (%) represents a string of zero or more characters.

```
SELECT email 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
```

This will ignore the following cases (simple version for valid emails):

- emails that have at least one character before the @;
- emails that have at least two characters between @ and .;
- emails that have at least two characters between . and the end.

You can see an example in MySql in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/026c7/1).

To add it as a constraint, you do (as mustaccio said in a comment):

```
alter table your_table add constraint chk_email check (email like '%_@__%.__%')
```

Comment: This works with DB2, I can confirm. To add a check constraint to an existing column, use `alter table your_table  add constraint chk_email check (email like '%_@__%.__%')`

Comment: There is no problem at all with your approach, I just wanted to indicate that I've tried both ways any they worked. another thing I thought actually it is possible to accept two answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a trigger that checks the given string with a regular expression that describes the structure of an email

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+.[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

However, the regular expression of an email is not easy to define: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

```
DECLARE RET VARCHAR(32);
SET RET = XMLCAST (
    XMLQUERY ('fn:matches($TEXT,"^[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+.[A-Za-z0-9]+$")' 
    PASSING TEXT AS "TEXT"
    ) AS VARCHAR(32));
```

Once you have the value of RET (true or false) you can do something in the trigger.

You can test the regular expression you want to use from command line:

```
db2 "xquery fn:matches(\"johndoe@mail.com\",\"^[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+.[A-Za-z0-9]+$\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring just @ wouldn't be an ideal check for validating email address.

Validation can be something like

```
SELECT Email FROM YourTable WHERE email NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Email, '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$')
```

or you can even do a simpler validation to reduce false negatives and run faster

```
SELECT Email FROM YourTable WHERE Email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
```